# Enquiry on complex valued functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be any differentiable function and $\theta$ be some complex number. Is it always the case that $\Re f(\theta) = \Re f(\overline \theta)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Consider the function 
$$f(\theta)=1+i\theta$$
and evaluate at $\theta=i$ and $\overline{\theta}=-i$.  Your statement holds true for 
$$f(\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\theta^n$$
if $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$, but not in general